# calculate long run dynamic multiplier

Tags: dynamic-regression, ardl

When calculating the long run multiplier in a dynamic model (ARDL) (no cointegration found so not ECM) should the coefficients that are not statistically significant also be included?

Comment: Hi Gus: Only variables that are going to be included in the final model should be used in the expression for the multiplier.